# Dual space induced by a finer topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ be two seminorms on a space $E$ such that $\|\cdot\|_2\geq\|\cdot\|_1$. Let further $E_i:=(E,\|\cdot\|_i)$ and

$$C_b(E_i):=\{f : E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\mid f \ \text{ bounded } \, \&\, \text{ continuous wrt.} \ \|\cdot\|_i\} \quad \text{ and }\quad X_i:={\big(C_b(E_i)\big)}'$$

be the [topological dual](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515403/dual-space-of-c-bx?noredirect=1&lq=1) of $C_b(E_i)$ ($i=1,2$). Do you know if the space $X_1$ can be 'canonically embedded' into $X_2$?

**Intuition:** Let $\tau_i$ denote the $\|\cdot\|_i$-induced topology on $E$. Since $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$, we have the inclusion of Borel-$\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(\tau_1)\subseteq\sigma(\tau_2)$ and hence might expect that each

$$\mu\in rba(E_2)\cong X_2 \quad \text{[somehow uniquely?] extends} \quad \mu_0:=\left.\mu\right|_{\sigma(\tau_1)}\in rba(E_1)\cong X_1$$

for $rba(E_i)$ [the space of finititely additive regular bounded Borel measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515403/dual-space-of-c-bx?noredirect=1&lq=1) on $E_i$.

Any hints or associated references are welcome.